# Get rid of ndk build from a project

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have added ndk support in my project because I needed to convert from one pixel format to another and I thought it would be faster in native code than in java. Now I realized I don't actually need to convert anything so I no longer need the ndk-build in my project. How do I get rid of android building the *.so files that I no longer use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `Eclipse` follow:

```
Project -> Properties -> Builders
```

and disable `CDT`

Answer (score 0):

Remove complete jni folder. 
Also from java remove all the native methods.Remove the libraries that are present under libs/armeabi

Also remove obj/local/armeabi